# How can I configure Spring Boot to connect a dockerized MySql database?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose

Whatever I try the following exception occurs when I start the project:
`java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

*application.properties*:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=MyPassword
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MyPassword

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

I successfully connect to that database loging into Adminer with the above mentioned credentials.

```
SELECT user, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

shows:

```
| user    | plugin
+---------+-----------------------
| root    | mysql_native_password
```

The database and Adminer are started in a docker-compose file and I start separately the Spring Boot project without using Docker. Can you please tell me what's wrong with the connection's configuration?

```
org.springframework.boot -> 3.0
OS -> Ubuntu 22.04
Dockerized MySql -> 8.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to the service running as docker container you also have to expose the MySQL ports:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    # NOTE: use of "mysql_native_password" is not recommended: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password
    # (this is just an example, not intended to be a production configuration)
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MyPassword
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that! Thanks, it works now!